# Insert string before and after dynamic string

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have following string..

```
string = 'bla bla bla data-id="34232" bla bla bla bla data-id="457667" bla bla bla bla bla bla data-id="45454" bla bla'
```

i need to replace into following string..

```
string = 'bla bla bla <div data-id="34232"></div> bla bla bla bla <div data-id="457667"></div> bla bla bla bla bla bla <div data-id="45454"></div> bla bla'
```

I was doing this..

```
string.match(/data-id="(.*?)"/g);
// ["data-id="34232"", "data-id="457667"", "data-id="45454""]
```

after that, I don't have idea how to accomplish this...

thank You for any help..

Comment: `string.replace(/that/, '<div data-id="$1"></div>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** to perform string replacement and use [`$&` which helps to inserts the matched substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in replacement string.

```js
var str = 'bla bla bla data-id="34232" bla bla bla bla data-id="457667" bla bla bla bla bla bla data-id="45454" bla bla';

console.log(
  str.replace(/data-id=".*?"/g, '<div $&></div>')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (using **split** and minor modification to your **regex**)

```
string = string.split(/(data-id=".*?)"/).map(function(val, index){ if ( index % 2== 1 ){ val = "<div " + val + "></div>" } return val; }).join("");
```

**DEMO**

```js
var string = 'bla bla bla data-id="34232" bla bla bla bla data-id="457667" bla bla bla bla bla bla data-id="45454" bla bla'
string = string.split(/(data-id=".*?)"/).map(function(val, index){ if ( index % 2== 1 ){ val = "<div " + val + "></div>" } return val; }).join("");
alert(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC6jW6/2).

You can capture the `data-id=` as well along with the value inside it and use it in the replacement.

```js
var s = 'bla bla bla data-id="34232" bla bla bla bla data-id="457667" bla bla bla bla bla bla data-id="45454" bla bla'
console.log(s.replace(/(data-id="\d+")/g, '<div $1></div>'));

// "bla bla bla <div data-id="34232"></div> bla bla bla bla <div data-id="457667"></div> bla bla bla bla bla bla <div data-id="45454"></div> bla bla"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.replace` function(with "replacer" function):

```
var str = 'bla bla bla data-id="34232" bla bla bla bla data-id="457667" bla bla bla bla bla bla data-id="45454" bla bla',
    wrapped = str.replace(/data-id=\"[^"]+\"/g, function(m){
        return "<div " + m + "></div>";
    });

console.log(wrapped);
// "bla bla bla <div data-id="34232"></div> bla bla bla bla <div data-id="457667"></div> bla bla bla bla bla bla <div data-id="45454"></div> bla bla"
```